# Not phased work. Is it normal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, after a complex cycle that processes the data from the database and writes them to a certain array, I need to process the data from the array. What happens is that the function of array processing is triggered without waiting for the mining cycle (filling in the array). Everything has to be done through the setTimeout ();
Is this normal?

```
checkDialog: function (data, callback) {
    var interlocutorsArray = JSON.parse(data);
    var dialogsId = {};
    mongoclient.open(function (err, cursor) {

        var db = cursor.db('messages');
        var dialogsDb = db.collection('dialog');
        interlocutorsArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
            dialogsDb.find({
                owner: item.owner_user_id,
                viewer: item.viewer_user_id
            }, function (err, cursor) {
                cursor.count(function (err, count) {
                    if (count === 0) {
                        dialogsDb.insert({
                            owner: item.owner_user_id,
                            viewer: item.viewer_user_id
                        }, function (err, inserting) {
                            dialogsId[inserting[0]._id] = {
                                owner: item.owner_user_id,
                                viewer: item.viewer_user_id
                            };
                        });
                    } else {
                        cursor.each(function (err, item) {
                            if (item !== null) {
                                dialogsId[item._id] = {
                                    owner: item.owner,
                                    viewer: item.viewer
                                };
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

    setTimeout((function () {
        callback(dialogsId);
    }), 150);

    console.log('after callback');

}
```

**Sorry for my bad English!**

Comment: You're in callback hell there.

Comment: @alex That's too bad: (
But, what do I do?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is?... Sorry...

Comment: @gillyb Look...I need to fill an array dialogsId data from the database. It turns out great. Next, I need to parse this array, this will be done after the main loop interlocutorsArray.forEach.
The problem is that dialogsId after the cycle is available only after some time. That is, now I can only get it through the setTimeout ();
How to avoid it?

Comment: Javascript is non-blocking so there is no wait for the processing to complete. You'll need to call a callback function after the processing  completes. And **no**. Setting a timeout isn't the normal way of doing this. It's also very unreliable. Callbacks are the normal way of handling things in javascript. If you're not comfortable with this you can always switch to something blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend you to switch from your current `mongodb` module to something more comfortable, such as:

- [monk](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk)
- [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin)
- [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)

I'll be using `monk` in my example, by it may be easily adapted for any `mongodb` module, including [native mongodb node driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

As for your problem, you may solve it with any module for asynchronous control flow management, such as:

- [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)
- most [A+/promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md), e.g. [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

Here's an example of solving your problem with `async.js`:

```
checkDialog: function (data, callback) {
  var db = require('monk')('localhost/messages');
  var dialogsDb = db.get('dialog');
  var interlocutorsArray = JSON.parse(data);

  async.concat(interlocutorsArray, function (item, next) {
    var query = {
      owner: item.owner_user_id
      viewer: item.viewer_user_id
    };
    dialogsDb.find(query, function (err, docs) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (docs && docs.length > 0) {
        next(null, docs);
      } else {
        dialogsDb.insert(query, function (err, inserting) {
          next(err, [inserting]);
        })
      }
    })
  }, function (err, items) {
    if (err) throw err; // it's best to handle errors without throwing them
    var dialogsId = {};
    for (var item, i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      item = items[i];
      dialogsId[item._id] = {
        owner: item.owner,
        viewer: item.viewer
      };
    }
    callback(dialogsId);
  })
}
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect! You've been very helpful to solve my problem! But, i do not quite understend your code. I would like to parse all in pieces. Не могли бы вы со мной связаться: romangorbatko(at)gmail.com. Thank you very much for your help!